# Getting an non-object error in my php script

Tags: php

Hey I was trying to call a script to made some changes to an html file, however when I run the script it tells me that it's making a call to a non-object. Obviously I did something wrong, but what? Here's the script.

```
    /*Dom controllers*/
    $dom = new DOMDocument();
    $dom->loadHTML('index.html');
    $id = $dom->getElementById('contact_us');
    $p = $dom->appendChild(new DOMElement('p'));
    $op = $dom->getElementsByTagName('p');

    /* Dem POST vars used by dat Ajax mah ziggen, yeah boi*/
    if (isset($_POST['Home']) && isset($_POST['About']) && isset($_POST['Contact']) && isset($_POST['sexyText'])){
    $home = $_POST['Home'];
    $about = $_POST['About'];
    $contact = $_POST['Contact'];
    $text = $_POST['sexyText'];
    trim($home);
    trim($about);
    trim($contact);
    trim($text);
    }

    function post(){
        global $dom, $id, $home, $about, $contact, $text, $textp, $p, $op;
                $textp = $dom->createTextNode($text);
                $p->appendChild($textp);
                $id->replaceChild($p, $op);
                $dom->saveHTMLFile('index.html');
    }


    post();
    echo 1;


?>
```

The error happens at the replaceChild function.

Comment: In line 145 you forgot the $this, or CAN YOU GIVE US THE ERROR MESSAGE + WHICH LINE?

Comment: Which line? We need a lot more context about the error message, though my bet would be on `loadHTML()` failing to parse an invalid HTML file.

Comment: Note that these don't really help you since you don't return the trimmed value: `trim($text)`.  Instead do `$text = !empty($_POST['sexyText']) ? trim($_POST['sexyText']) "";`

Comment: The line is the replaceChild line, it's odd because the HTML file is valid and I'm sure the id name is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
            $id->replaceChild($p, $op);
```

At this point, `$op` is actually a DOMNodeList, returned by your getElementsByTagName call. You cannot use a nodelist for a replaceChild call - it expects a DOMNode, not DOMNodeList.

Comment: So I assume doing something like `$id->replaceChild($p, $id->firstChild);` should work then.

Comment: Or `$op->item(0)`, though for safety's sake you should check if $op actually has a list of nodes. It'd still be a domnodelist if no match tags were found, it's just have a 0-length list.